# Best method to supply a storage statement with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, sqlite, firefox-addon

What's the "best" method to supply a statement with mutliple parameters? I want to insert a single line into an SQLite database.

Adapting https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage#Binding_Parameters I thought the following would work:

```js
var conn = Services.storage.openDatabase(dbfile); // Will also create the file if it does not exist
let statement  = conn.createStatement("INSERT INTO persons (name, email, city) VALUES (:name, :email, :city)");
statement.params.name = myName;
statement.params.email = myEmail;
statement.params.city = myCity;
```

But obviously I can't even create the statement itself:

> Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

After that I'd like to execute it asynchronously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you show here - it works correctly. However, `createStatement` will validate the SQL code and throw an `NS_ERROR_FAILURE` error if that code is invalid. In your case either the table `persons` doesn't exist or not all of the fields `name`, `email` and `city` exist in it. You should take a look at the [`lastErrorString` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozIStorageConnection#Attributes) to see the error message:

```js
let statement = null;
try
{
  statement = conn.createStatement("INSERT INTO persons (name, email, city) VALUES (:name, :email, :city)");
}
catch (e)
{
  Components.utils.reportError(conn.lastErrorString);
}
```